# I am getting firebase permission error. Even though I did it according to the firebase rules, it doesn't work

Tags: ios, swiftui, firebase-security

Hi firebase I wanted to upload pdf doc style data from icloud by connecting to simulator. but I am getting a user access error. I don't want to have a user already in my application. What I did as in the firebase documentation is still not working.
also allow read, write: if true; I haven't tried it still does not allow access

Firebase;

```
  rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

SwiftUI contentview;

```
import SwiftUI
import MobileCoreServices
import Firebase
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var show = false
    @State var alert = false
    var body: some View {
       
        
        Button {
            
            self.show.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("Document Picker")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $show)
        {
            DocumentPicker(alert: self.$alert)
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $alert) {
            
            Alert(title: Text("Opps Wonderful"), message: Text("OKey Upload"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        }   }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


struct DocumentPicker : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return DocumentPicker.Coordinator(parent1: self)
    }
    
    @Binding var alert: Bool
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext <DocumentPicker> ) -> UIDocumentPickerViewController {
        
        
        let picker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes:            [String(kUTTypeItem)]  , in: .open)
        picker.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
}
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIDocumentPickerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPicker>) {
        
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
      
        var parent : DocumentPicker
        
        init (parent1: DocumentPicker)
        {
            parent = parent1
        }
        
        func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
          
            let bucket = Storage.storage().reference()

            bucket.child((urls.first?.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent)!).putFile(from: urls.first!,metadata: nil   ){
                (_, err) in
               
                if err != nil {
                    print ((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
        print("succeess")
                self.parent.alert.toggle()
        
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Dude honestly just use something else than Firebase. You are going to regret it. Google has designed something that fights iOS at every step of the way, and there are bunches of caveats that are only apparent when it's too late.

Comment: You can already see from your code that the Firebase SDK isn't symbiotic with how iOS apps are written. In general you just gotta submit and conform to whatever Apple wants. Try to solve your thing with CoreData instead, I guarantee that obeying our Cupertino overlords will result in better design, code and reliability.

Comment: Google is also famous for killing popular projects or revamping them into new and flashy things. They never let something mature and become reliable. As you've probably noticed their documentation is fragmented and confusing due to this bonuses-for-new-products structure.

Comment: thanks you are right. Do you have a database that you would recommend instead of Firebase?

Comment: Parse was great, then Facebook bought it and killed it. Realm was cool, but Mongo bought them and ruined it. Firebase is made by Google. I am in the same boat, having built a large app on top of Realm.

Comment: My experience is that you should just copy Apple. They are the best at making products. Apple build their apps using CoreData. You can solve pretty much anything with CoreData. If you are creating some sort of social media app, you need an external server as well. If you are simply storing files for the user and sharing it with limited people, you can do with CoreData.

Comment: CoreData + CloudKit has everything you need built in. using those will give your users the best privacy. Because iOS has an account for your user, you don't need to add auth. It stores data in the users private account, so you do not need to pay for server storage.

Comment: The downside is that it is hard to learn. There is a lot of stuff to understand. You should watch some WWDC videos to get started. It is hard, but worth it in the end

Answer (score 0):

The security rules you're showing are for Cloud Firestore (a document database), while your code is using Cloud Storage (file storage). While both are part of Firebase, they each have their own API and their own security rules, and the security rules of one don't apply to the other.

You'll want to study the [documentation on securing Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security), and then set the [security rules for Cloud Storage in your project](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/storage/).

Comment: thanks,I understand Firebase Security Rules, it doesn't allow even though I do. interesting system

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean there. Can you rephrase as a question?

Comment: Hey @AlfaOmega Can you rephrase your last comment?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I just don't understand the firebase rules.

Comment: That's not a question, which makes it hard to provide an answer . ¯\_(ツ)_/¯   I recommend reading the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules) and posting back if you have a concrete question.